# Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modulo Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27860/modulo-arithmetic)

How would you find x in a modulo arithmetic expression x^e mod p knowing only e and p?

e is an integer, 0 ≤ e < p, that is relatively prime to p-1; and x is an integer, 0 ≤ x < p.

Comment: I noticed that you commented on the previous question that you forgot the ^ in the expression x^e. You should edit your previous question to add it in, not post a whole new question.

Comment: Actually not a duplicate:  I missed the exponent symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Discrete Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem, and is not easy.