# Is there an easy expression for multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: group-theory, functions, finite-fields

I know that in arbitrary division rings, one can go about finding inverses Euclidean division. But take $\mathbb Z_{11}$ as a simple example. Is there a "nice" expression which yields the inverses in general? i.e. an expression $e(n)$ such that

$$
e(1) = 1, \quad
e(2) = 6, \quad
e(3) = 4, \quad
e(4) = 3, \quad
e(5) = 9, \quad
e(6) = 2, \quad
e(7) = 8, \quad
e(8) = 7, \quad
e(9) = 5, \quad
e(10) = 10,
$$

all up to mod 11.

I tried polynomial interpolation, but ended up with this ugly thing:

$$-\frac{7 x^9}{2160}+\frac{77
   x^8}{480}-\frac{4279
   x^7}{1260}+\frac{28919
   x^6}{720}-\frac{4653
   x^5}{16}+\frac{1911679
   x^4}{1440}-\frac{4091593
   x^3}{1080}+\frac{2321143
   x^2}{360}-\frac{1229503
   x}{210}+2123,$$

which isn't surprising, given the points it should pass through:

[image]

Naturally this does not account for modulo 11, so probably one can get something better if polynomial interpolation can be adapted up to mod 11. Or maybe the expression isn't a polynomial at all, maybe it can include a factorial term? I'm mentioning this because I tried to play around with Wilson's theorem but this didn't yield anything immediately useful.

Comment: To find inverses, you need the extended Euclidean algorithm in general. Only in special cases, they can be found easier.

Comment: For small $a$ we can give an explicit formula (closed form)  for $\,a^{-1}\bmod n\,$ using Inverse Reciprocity, e.g. I do that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191201/242) for $\,a = 5.\,$ But generally this involves about $\ a/2\,$ cases so it is not practical for large $\,a.$ $\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a nice and simple polynomial (over the field $\mathbb F_p$): namely,
  $$ x \mapsto x^{p-2}. $$
If you want to map the *integers* $[0,p-1]$ to themselves, combine this with the fractional part function:
  $$ x\mapsto p\left\{\frac{x^{p-2}}{p}\right\}. $$

Comment: Yes that is indeed a simple formula ! More generally, the inverse of $a$ mod $m$ when $\gcd(a,m)=1$ is $a^{\phi(m)-1}$. But, for large $p$, it is slower than the Euclidean Algorithm as a means of calculating $a^{-1}$.

Comment: Of course, because $\mathbb F_p\setminus \{0\}$ is a group! I can't believe I missed this. Thank you.

Comment: @DerekHolt, if we use square-and-multiply as an algorithm for computing the power mod $p$, it only takes $O(\log p)$ steps, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett That's true, but according to the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) it is still slower than using the extended euclidean  algorithm.