# Simplification of a simple expression

Tags: arithmetic

I'm going through an answer on this site, and I can't see how

$7−2(31−4(7))$ simplifies to $9(7)−2(31)$

What rule is being used here?

source: [How to find the inverse modulo m?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m)

Comment: notice that 9=1-2(4)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $7 - 2(31-4(7)) = 7 - 2*31 + 2*4*7 = 7 + 8*7 - 2*31 = 9(7) - 2(31)$. Just expand the 2 in and simplify.