# How to calculate -69^(-1) mod 1313

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which method should I use to calculate
$-69^{-1}  \mod  1313?$

Comment: Which methods do you know? Hint: ($1313 = 13\cdot 101$, both prime)

Comment: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25390/186012).