# How do you find a multiplicative inverse in modulo arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In one of my lectures I have been given this example:

[image]

When Googling 'multiplicative inverse' most of the tutorials seem to indicate it's as easy as just multiplying a number by the number divided by 1. What's different in this example? How do you work out a multiplicative inverse when it's $\mathbb{Z}_7$ ?

Also, how exactly is the additive inverse calculated?

Comment: See Item 31. and 32.http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/guide/section/14soln.pdf and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m

Comment: You might gain some insight by working out the multiplication table (resp. the addition table) for $\mathbb{Z}_7$, the integers modulo $7$.

Comment: One way to find these if $n$ is small is by trial and error.

Answer (score 7):

You use what is called the extended Euclidean algorithm. Here is an example:

Let's say we want to find the inverse of $5$ mod $7$. We first seek to find integers $a$ and $b$ such that:

$5a + 7b = 1$ (note that this is a Bezout identity).

Having done so, mod $7$, we wind up with:

$5a = 1$ (mod $7$), so $a$ (mod $7$) is the inverse we're after.

So how do we find $a$ (and the $b$ we don't really care about)?

First we divide $7$ by $5$, to get:

$7 = 1\cdot 5 + 2$.

Next, we divide $5$ by $2$, to get:

$5 = 2\cdot 2 + 1$.

Now...we "work backwards":

$1 = 5 - 2(2)$

But $2 = 7 - 5$, so we get:

$1 = 5 - 2(7 - 5) = 5 - 2(7) + 2(5) = 3(5) - 2(7)$.

Thus $a = 3$, and $b = -2$.

So $5^{-1}$ (mod $7$) is $3$ (mod $7$).

Comment: yes, the multiplicative inverse equation in  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$  becomes a linear equation in $\mathbb{Z}$ (diophantine equation) which is easy to solve with the extended $\text{gcd}$ algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation

Comment: Indeed, and I could have answered in more generality. But I wanted to illustrate that it's not really that difficult to do, and only involves pretty basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

To get the additive inverse, subtract the number from the modulus, which in this case is $7$.  (except that $0$ is its own inverse)  For example, the additive inverse of $5$ is $7-5=2$.

To get the multiplicative inverse is trickier, you need to find a number that multiplied by $n$ is one more than a multiple of $7$.  For example, $5^{-1}$ is $3$ because $5\cdot 3=15$, which is one more than a multiple of $7$.

Comment: To add on a bit to vadim's answer, there exist some algorithms for solving for the multiplicative inverse (due to Euler). A brief introduction to this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). The extended Euclidian Algorithm has complexity $O(\log(m)^2)$

Answer (score 0):

1*1= 1, 2*4= 8= 7+ 1= 1 (mod 7), 3*5= 15= 2(7)+ 1= 1 (mod 7), and then 4*2= 1 (mod 7), 5*3= 1 (mod 7), 6*6= 36= 5(7)+ 1= 1 (mod 7).  So the multiplicative inverse of 1 is 1, the multiplicative inverse of 2 IS 4, the multiplicative inverse of 3 is 5, the multiplicative inverse of 4 is 2, the multiplicative inverse of 5 is 3, and the multiplicative of 6 is 6 (all "mod 7").