# how to solve an equation (132 * y = 17 (modulo 35 )) modulo i

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have this equation :

> 132 * y = 17 (modulo 35 )

How do I find y?I suspect that there is no solution ,but how do i prove this ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem yourself? Where did you get stuck? What did you try to do to unstuck yourself?

Comment: what have you done and use latex. In the title does that mean something?

Comment: Use proper [formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your posts here. And show your work, whatever you have done.

Comment: @Oana, I believe that your assumption about the non-existence of the decision you made at random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclid's algorithm

$$132=35\cdot 3 + 27$$
$$35 = 27\cdot 1 + 8$$
$$27 = 8\cdot 3 + 3$$
$$8 = 3\cdot 2 + 2$$
$$3 = 2\cdot 1 + 1$$

Now we substitute the previous equations into the last one.

$$3 = (8-3\cdot2)\cdot1 + 1$$
$$(27-8\cdot 3) = (8-3\cdot2)\cdot1 + 1$$
and so on until

$$13\cdot132 - 35\cdot 49 = 1$$
that tells you that $13$ is the inverse of $132$ mod $35$.
Therefore the solution is $y=13\cdot17$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve the equation
$$
132y+35x=17
$$
so first we solve the equation
$$
132y+35x=1
$$
and multiply the particular solution by $17$. Using the extended Euclidean algorithm detailed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&3&1&3&2&1&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&4&-9&\color{#C00}{13}&\color{#C00}{-35}\\
0&1&-3&4&-15&34&-49&132\\
\color{#090}{132}&\color{#090}{35}&27&8&3&2&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
which says that $y=13-35k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying the particular solution by $17$, we get the final solution to be
$$
y=221-35k
$$
Setting $k=6$, gives the smallest positive solution to be $y=11$.

Answer (score 1):

By employing $\rm\color{#c00}{even\ reps}$ **to divide by 2** (or 4) the modular fraction is easily mentally computable:

${\rm mod}\ 35\!:\ \dfrac{17}{132}\equiv\dfrac{\color{#c00}{-18}}{-\color{}8}\equiv \dfrac{9}4\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{44}}4\equiv 11 $

The key idea is: if the modulus $m$ is odd then $\,2\mid a\,$ or $\,2\mid \color{#c00}{a\!\pm\!m},\,$ so we can quickly divide $\,a\,$ by $\,2\,$ by choosing a rep that is *even*. Iterating that we can easily divide by all powers of $\,2\,$ (e.g $\,8\,$ above).

**Alternatively** $ $it's very simply computed by the [*fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)

${\rm mod}\,\ 35\!:\,\ \dfrac{0}{35} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{17}{-8} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-2}3\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{11}1$

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you solve ordinary linear equations. You multiply both sides by the inverse of $132$. We need to find some number $d$ such that $d\cdot 132 = 1\mod 35$. For this you can use Euclid's algorithm since that equation is the same as $$132d-35k=1$$

Alternatively, since 35 is not very large you can try $d=1,2,3,...,34$ to see which one works.