# Solve the congruence : $3n^{3}+2\equiv 0 \pmod{1163}$ where $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Problem :

I'm going today to find all natural number such that : 
$1163 \mid 3n^{3}+2$ 
Mathematical give $n \equiv 435 \mod 1163$

My little try :

first we note that $1163$ prime number

$3n^{3}\equiv -2 \pmod{1163}$

Now I don't know how I complete my work 
My be we can use Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Is it $3n^3\equiv 2$ or $3n^3+2\equiv 0$?

Comment: Sorry just $(-2)$ , see now

Comment: Related to [OP's earlier question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386999/242)

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to find that $3^{-1} \equiv 388 \pmod{1163}$ (can be done with Euclid's algorithm). So
$$
3n^3 + 2 \equiv 0 \iff n^3 \equiv -2\cdot 388 \equiv 387 \pmod{1163}
$$
We know that $(\mathbb Z/1163\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic, because $1163$ is prime. If $(\mathbb Z/1163\mathbb Z)^\times = \langle x \rangle$, then $x^3$ also generates the group, because $3$ and $1162$ (the order of the group) are coprime. That means that $a\mapsto a^3$ is an automorphism (in particular a bijection) of $(\mathbb Z/1163\mathbb Z)^\times$. In other words, any equation $n^3 \equiv m \pmod{1163}$ has a unique solution.

Now we need to find the solution. Note that $3^{-1} \equiv 775\pmod{1162}$. Thus:
$$
n^3 \equiv 387 \equiv 387^{3\cdot 775} \pmod{1163}
$$
Which gives $n\equiv 387^{775} \equiv 435 \pmod{1163}$.

EDIT: How to find $3^{-1}$ (with a general approach).

Use the Euclidean algorithm on $(1163,3)$:
$$
1163 = 387 \cdot 3 + 2 \\
3 = 1 \cdot 2 + 1
$$
Now we work backwards:
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= 3 - 1\cdot 2 \\
&= 3 - 1 \cdot (1163 - 387\cdot 3) \\
&= 388\cdot 3 - 1\cdot 1163
\end{align}
$$
We see that $388\cdot 3 \equiv 1\pmod{1163}$, so $3^{-1} \equiv 388 \pmod{1163}$. The same approach can be used to find $3^{-1} \equiv 775\pmod{1162}$.

Comment: Thanks sir @Milten , but how you get $\frac{1}{3}\equiv 388\pmod{1163}$

Comment: or note -2 is 1161, leading to $n^3\equiv 387\equiv -776$  neither of which is a cube normally so we can eliminate -9 to 7 from possibilities.

Comment: @EllenEllen $1164/3= 388$

Comment: Ooh , OK @Macphee thank you very much , actually I don't understand all the solution

Comment: @EllenEllen Both of Roddy MacPhee's suggestions are good. For a general approach, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation). I believe the Euclidean algorithm is usually preferred. There are also a bunch of questions on this site about it.

Comment: @EllenEllen You can also find it as $3^{-1}\equiv 3^{1162-1}$, but that is quite inefficient to compute.

Comment: @EllenEllen In short: Use the Euclidean algorithm on $(1163, 3)$ until you get to the last line $r_k = r_{k+1}+1$. Then you can substitute backwards in your equations to write $3x+1163y=1$, which means $3^{-1} \equiv x$.

Comment: Let me see @Milten , then I tell you if I get it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\,\ $ $3^{\large 7}\! = 2^{\large 10}\! + 1163\,$ $\Rightarrow\, \bmod 1163\!:\  n^{\large 3}\equiv {-}\dfrac{2}3 \equiv \left[\dfrac{-9}8\right]^{\large 3}$ and $\ \,  \dfrac{-9}8 \equiv\,  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\!435}$

Comment: Generally it's best to compute cube roots as in Milten's answer. but here we exploit special structure to make the computation amenable to easy mental arithmetic.

Comment: The modular fraction can be easily computed by [using *even* reps to divide by $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326318/242) or by [Gauss's algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

Comment: Thank you very much , but i dont understand this way , its new for me , can you give me another example or Link!!

Comment: @Ellen We sought $\,j,k\,$ with $\, 3^{\large 3j+1} \equiv 2^{\large 3k+1}$ so $\, (3^{\large j}/2^{\large k})^{\large 3} \equiv 2/3,\, $ and our first choice worked, i.e. $\,3j\!+\!1=7\,$ is the least power of $\,3\,$ that is $\,> 1163\ \ \ $