# What is meant by "Calculate the inverse of the following elements"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In the following task I have been instructed to "Calculate the inverse of the following elements".

Searching for what the [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) could mean here as well as what the notation of F could mean in a list of [mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) has been fruitless in aiding my understanding of the assigned task.

I am hoping someone with a more trained mathematical eye can tell me what is being asked here.

[image: Exercise tasks a and b]

Note: It is possible that the Tags are misnomers, I have tried to make an educated guess based on what subjects we are doing at Uni. Apologies in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: $\Bbb F_n$ is also known as $\Bbb Z_n$, $\Bbb Z/(n)$ and $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. The notation $\Bbb F_n$ is meant to emphasise that it's a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overline is showing that the value is a representative member of the [congruence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_classes) (or residue class).

$\Bbb F_n$ is referring to the finite field for modular arithmetic on that prime $n$. In general modular arithmetic  modulo $n$  is on the ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ but for $n$ prime this is a field.

An inverse of $a \bmod m$ is looking a number (residue) $k$  such that $ak\equiv 1 \bmod m$. Then $k$ is the inverse of $a \bmod m$, which may be written as  $k\equiv a^{-1} \bmod m$

For example, the inverse of $5 \bmod 17$ is $7$ because $5\cdot 7=35\equiv 1 \bmod 17$.

In general to find the modular inverse you can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers). Some more discussion on finding these at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to utilize this method to calculate the solutions a) 12 and b) 580 respectively.

I have not yet grasped the concept of a field, so i will inform myself on this topic next.

Comment: It's probably easier to simply work at modular arithmetic and then later - when you encounter fields in a more generic sense - you will have an example to refer to.