# Euler's totient function - prove the product formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, totient-function

Let n $\prod_{i=1}^k p_{i}^{e_i}$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $p_i\neq p_j \in \mathbb{P}, \quad \forall i\neq j$ and $e_i \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Then for Euler's totient function follows:

$$\phi(n)=\prod_{i=1}^k (p_i-1)p_{i}^{e_i-1}$$

I have to prove this theorem in the 3 following steps:

1) The formula holds for $n=p^{e_i}$.

This step is done by considering that all numbers $k$ with $gcd(n,k)\neq 1$ have to be multiplicatives of p and there are $p^{e_i-1}$ of them, therefore $\phi(n)=p^{e_i}-p^{e_i-1}$.

2) A residue class is prime modulo $m$, iff it is a unit in the multiplicative  semigroup of $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

3) Use the Chinese remainder theorem and (2) to reduce the problem for arbitrary $n$ to the one of the prime power.

My problem is that I don't know how to prove that for any unit in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ follows that it has to be a prime residue class. The other direction clear to me I can state it if needed.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: can you use the multiplication property of $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$ if $\gcd(n,m)=1$? or can you prove this? see for example the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_product_formula

Comment: i know that this is a way to prove the product formula but have to stick to those 3 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good strategy.

It's not quite true that the residue class must be prime, but instead that it must be coprime to $m$.

For $x$ to be a unit in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the same as saying there exists $y$ such that $xy \equiv 1 \bmod m$. In this phrasing, the question is to show that such a $y$ exists exactly when $x$ is coprime to $m$.

We show that if there exists such a $y$, then $x$ must be coprime to $m$ first. The congruence $xy \equiv 1 \bmod m$ implies that there is a $z$ such that $xy + mz = 1$. Any common divisor of $x$ and $m$ must divide $1$, and thus $x$ and $m$ are coprime.

For the converse, we must show that if $\gcd(x,m) = 1$ then $xy \equiv 1 \pmod m$ has a solution (for $y$). This is a classical question (perhaps generally called finding modular inverses), and one typically constructively proves this using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25392/9754) for example.

Together, these imply that the size of the multiplicative group of units for a prime power is $\lvert(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times \rvert = p^n - p^{n-1}$, completing your middle step.

Comment: Thank you very much, i don't know how i could not see this. The converse  i got on my own.