# Get back original value after some modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Let $p$ be a value between $0 - 100$.

Let $k$ be any prime key less than $50,$ say $47$.

Let $n$ be any number, for this case say $200$.

I do the operation
$$ 
p \leftarrow (p\cdot k)\pmod n
$$
I have the new value of $p$ only. How would I reverse this operation i.e. get back the original value of $p$?

I know I have to think of multiplicative modular inverse, but how would I go about it?

Comment: If you know already that the modular inverse solves your question, find out how to compute it, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m).

Comment: It's not in the form of a standard modular inverse. It's x = kx mod p

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the computed value is $x_0$ i.e.
$$
x_0=(p\cdot k)\pmod n
$$
Now assuming we only know $x_0,k$ and $n$, we need to find the value of $p$. Notice that we would have gotten the same value $x_0$ had we taken $p+m\cdot n$ for any $m\in\mathbb Z$ instead of $p$ in the computation. So we cannot get back the actual value of $p$ that we started with, unless additional information is given.

With the example constraints you gave for $p,k$ and $n,$ I'm guessing that $p\leq n$. If modular inverse of $k$ w.r.t $n$ exists i.e. $\gcd(k,n)=1,$ then
$$
p=(x_0\cdot k^{-1})\pmod n
$$
is the unique value $\leq n$.

Otherwise, if $\gcd(k,n)=d,$ then there are exactly $d$ values of $p\leq n$ given by
$$
p=\left(p_0+\frac{n}{d}\cdot t\right)\pmod n\qquad t\in\mathbb Z,\;0\leq t\leq d-1
$$
where $p_0$ is any particular value satisfying the equation.

PS: Here is a link to a nice article on linear congruences if you're interested.
[linear-congruences](http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/linear-congruences.article.pdf)