# Find the smallest positive integer, whose last $4-digit$ part is $2010$ and is divisible by $2011$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, euclidean-algorithm

Find the smallest positive integer, whose last $4-digit$ part is $2010$ and is divisible by $2011$.

I solved it in the following way:

I state that $a$ is the number in front of $2010$, in other words if the number we're looking for is $A$, then $A=10^4\cdot a+2010$.

Hence, $a\cdot10^4\equiv1\bmod2011$.

$1956a\equiv1\bmod2011$

$55a\equiv2010\bmod2011$

So $55a=2010+2011k$ for some positive integer $k$.

So $30+31k\equiv 0 \bmod55$

After doing some trial and error for $k\in[0,54]$

$k_{min}=15$

So $55a=32175$, $a=585$.

Hence the smallest number possible is $5850000$

I solved this question using classical number theory and trial-and-error. However, I realize that this question can be solved using the euclidean algorithm. When I looked it up on the internet the only thing I could find was this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm which is how to find the gcd using euclid's algorithm. Could you please explain to me how to solve the question using the euclidean algorithm, and also please explain to me what the euclidean algorithm is, how it can be applied and some resources to study from?

Comment: You might find it helpful to read about [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) .  That's really just the Euclidean algorithm but in a form suited to modular arithmetic.

Comment: What exactly is "last 4 minus digit part" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{2011}\!:\,\ 10^4\! = 5(2000)\equiv 5(-11)\,$ so by simple mental arithmetic

$\ \ \dfrac{1}{10^4}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}1}{-5}\dfrac{1}{11} \equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-2010}}{-5}\dfrac{1}{11}\equiv\dfrac{402}{11}\equiv \dfrac{402+\color{#0a0}{2011\cdot \color{#90f}3}}{11} \equiv\, \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{585}$

We used [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) $\bmod 11\!:\ 0\equiv 402+\color{#0a0}{2011\cdot \color{#90f}k}\equiv 6\!-\!2k\!\iff\! \color{#90f}{k\equiv 3}\,$ makes *exact* the quotient by $11,\,$ and we [cast out $11$'s,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) e.g. $\bmod 11:\ 2011\equiv -2\!+\!0\!-1\!+\!1\equiv-2$.

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{-5} = \dfrac{1+2011(\color{#c00}{k})}{-5}$ can also be made an *exact quotient* by using inverse reciprocity, but the solution $\,\color{#c00}{k=-1}\,$ is obvious here, since $\,1\equiv 2011\pmod{\!5}\,$ is obvious, so it suffices to $\rm\color{#c00}{subtract}$ them: $\,1-2011\equiv \color{#c00}{-2010}\,$ to get an integer divisible by $5.\,$ That's what we did above.

Comment: In case it is not clear, the above method is one of many variations on the (extended) Euclidean algorithm (used for computing modular fractions and inverses), as will become clear if you follow the links.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: just found another way. Not the simplest but very safe and calculator-free because dividing by 10 is easy.

$$
\pmod{2011}: \frac{1}{10^4} \equiv \frac{-2010}{10^4}  \equiv \frac{-201+2011}{10^3} \equiv \frac{181-2011}{100} \equiv \frac{-183+2011\cdot 3}{10} = 585.
$$

---

I recently learned Gauss's Algorithm from Bill Dubuque ([How to find the inverse modulo m?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m/25395#25395)). Let's try:

$$
\frac{1}{10^4}\equiv \frac{1}{-55} \equiv \frac{36}{-55\cdot 36} \equiv \frac{36}{31} \equiv \frac{36\cdot 65}{31\cdot 65} \equiv \frac{329}{4} \equiv \frac{329+2011}{4}=\frac{2340}{4} =585 \pmod{2011}.\blacksquare
$$

Or, even simpler
$$
\frac{1}{10^4}\equiv \frac{-2010}{-55} = \frac{402}{11} \equiv \frac{402\cdot 183}{11\cdot 183} \equiv \frac{1170}{2} = 585 \pmod{2011}.
$$

Comment: +1 Good work. Yes. Gauss's algorithm will handle it fine as it will for any prime modulus. But here we can simplify a little by using inverse reciprocity as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$30+31k \equiv 0 \pmod{55}$$

$$31k \equiv -30 \equiv 25 \pmod{55}$$

Let us find $31^{-1}\pmod{55}$

\begin{align}
55 &= 31 + 24\\
31 &= 24 + 7 \\
24 &= 3(7)+3 \\
7 &= 2(3)+1
\end{align}

Hence we can write
\begin{align}
1 &= 7 - 2(3)\\
&= 7 - 2(24-3(7))\\
&=7(7)-2(24) \\
&= 7(31-24) - 2(24)\\
&= 7(31)-9(24)\\
&= 7(31) - 9(55-31)\\
&= 16(31) - 9(55)
\end{align}

Hence we can conclude that $31^{-1} \equiv 16 \pmod{55}$.

From $31k \equiv 25 \pmod{55}$, we have

$$k \equiv 31^{-1}(25) \equiv 16(25) \equiv 400 \equiv 15\pmod{55} $$

which agrees with your solution. They key is to learn to find the modulo inverse.

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for your response. Where can I learn to find the modular inverse?

Comment: Perhaps the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fz1vxq5ts5I) version might help.

Comment: Brilliant. That is exactly what I wanted. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean Algorithm

$A= 10000K + 2010 = 2011M$ so

$10000K = 2011M -2010 = 2011M-2011 +1 = 2011(M-1) = 1$

$10000K -2011(M-1) = 1$.

Find a small solution to $K, M-1$.

$10000 = 4*2011 + 1956;$ $1956=10000 - 4*2011$

$2011=1956 + 55;$ $55= 2011-1956 = 2011-(10000 -4*2011)=5*2011-10000$.

$1956 = 35*55 + 31;$ $31=1956-35*55= (10000-4*2011)- 35(5*2011-10000)= 36*10000-179*2011$

$55 = 31 + 24;$  $24 = 55-31 = (5*2011-10000)- (36*10000-179*2011)=-37*10000+184*2011$

$31 = 24 + 7;$  $7 =31 -24 =(36*10000-179*2011) -  (-37*10000+184*2011)=73*10000 -363*2011$

$24 = 3*7 + 3;$ $3=24-3*7=(-37*10000+184*2011)-3(73*10000 -363*2011)=-256*10000+1273*2011$

$7 = 2*3 + 1$ $1= 7-2*3 = (73*10000 -363*2011)- 2(-256*10000+1273*2011)=585*10000-2909*2011$

So if we let $K=585$ and $M-1=2909$ we get $5852010 = 2011*2910$

Comment: You're doing the extended Euclidean algorithm **backwards** - which is less clear and far more error-prone than doing it **forwards** as [explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242). Once you learn how to go forward you will never go back.