# Extraneous roots while solving a modular quadratic equation (congruence)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

\begin{gather}
\frac{N^2+N}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
N^2+N\equiv 0\\
(N+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}\equiv 0\\
4(N+\frac{1}{2})^2-1\equiv 0\\
2^2(N+\frac{1}{2})^2\equiv 1\\
(2N+1)^2\equiv 1 \\
2N+1 \equiv 1\\
2N=0\\
N=2,4,6,8...\\
2N+1 \equiv 3\\
2N=2\\
N=1,3,5,7...\\
\end{gather}
In other words I've shown $\forall N >0 \to \frac{N^2+N}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, which is false e.g. for $N=3$,  $\frac{N^2+N}{2}$ has a remainder of 2

I'd like a correct solution as well. Thanks.

Comment: What is 1/2 in mod4 arithmetic? And what is 1/4?

Comment: @Peter I multiplied by four to get rid of them.

Comment: But 4 = 0, and anything multiplied by 0 is 0

Comment: @Peter . So how do I solve this?

Comment: if division by zero is allowed, then all numbers are equal. If you can't, then you can't have 1/4 at any step. Similarly for 2 $(=\sqre{0})$

Comment: You are assuming $\frac 12$ and $\frac 14$ are well defined.  They are not.  If $\frac 12\equiv m\pmod 4$ and $\frac 14\equiv n \pmod 4$ exists then $2m\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $4n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  But there are no such equivalence classes in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first error is that you you scaled by $\,2,\,$ which is *not invertible* $\!\bmod 4,\,$ so this [will not yield an *equivalent* congruence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3925885/242) Rather, it yields *necessary* but not sufficient conditions on roots (so possibly  *extraneous* roots). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20unidirectional) for more on the *insufficiency* of unidirectional inferences.

To get an *equivalent* congruence we need to scale the *modulus* too, since $\,4\mid a/2\iff 8\mid a,\,$ so

$$(n^2+n)/2\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{4}\iff n^2+n\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{8}\qquad$$

Now we can complete the square as you did, but since this too involves scaling the modulus, this will end up being fruitless, leading back to where we started, namely

$$\begin{align} n^2+n&\equiv 0\pmod{8}\\
\iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 4n^2+4n&\equiv 0\pmod{32}\\
\iff 4n^2+4n+1&\equiv 1\pmod{32}\\
\iff \ \ \ \ \ \, \color{#c00}{(2n+1)^2}&\:\color{#c00}{\equiv 1}\pmod{32}\\
\iff (2n)(2n+2)&\equiv 0\pmod{32}\\
\iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \  n(n+1)&\equiv 0\pmod{8}
\end{align}\qquad$$

where we solved $\,\color{#c00}{a^2\equiv 1}\,$ by factoring the difference of squares $\,0\equiv a^2-1\equiv (a-1)(a+1).\,$  You can't simply take square roots as you did, e.g. $\,x^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}\,$ has $4$ roots $\,x\equiv 1,3,5,7$.

Instead, by $\,n,\,n\!+\!1\,$ coprime, $\,8\mid n(n\!+\!1)\iff 8\mid n\,$ or $\,8\mid n\!+\!1,\,$ thus we conclude that  $\,n(n+1)/2\equiv 0\pmod{4}\iff n\equiv 0,7\pmod{8}$

Finally, beware that modular fractions are well-defined (uniquely exist) only when they are writable with denominator coprime to the modulus, when $\,a/b := ab^{-1}.\,$ For more on modular fractions see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3001866/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242).

Answer (score 3):

What you did incorrectly is basically explained in [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/778779/peter)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4030152/602049), and several question comments. Note, though, the more general issue when manipulating congruences, since you are really dealing with integers, is that involving "fractions" of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, really means the division by $q$ is multiplying by its modulo multiplicative inverse, i.e., $q^{-1}$. However, only integers which are relatively prime to the modulus have inverses. Since $\gcd(4, 4) = 4 \neq 1$ and $\gcd(4, 2) = 2 \neq 1$, neither $2$ nor $4$ have an inverse in modulo $4$, so while working in that modulus you can't, in general, just "divide" by either value, e.g., $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ don't make sense.

As for how to correctly solve your congruence equation, note for any solution $N$, there's some integer $j$ where

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \frac{N^2 + N}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \iff \frac{N^2 + N}{2} = 4j \iff \\
& N^2 + N = 8j \iff N^2 + N \equiv 0 \pmod{8}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Due to $N$ and $N + 1$ being relatively prime to each other, with one being odd and one being even, then since $8 = 2^3$ has only prime factors of $2$, this then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& N(N + 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{8} \implies \\
& (N \equiv 0 \pmod{8}) \lor (N + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}) \implies \\
& N \equiv 0, 7 \pmod{8}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means the allowed values for $N$ are $N = 8k$ and $N = 8k + 7$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $N^2+N= 8j=4(2j)$ isn't $N^2+N\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $N\equiv 0,3 \pmod 4$

Comment: @user716881 Yes, $N \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ is *necessary*, but it's not *sufficient*. Consider if $N \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ but $N \not\equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, i.e., $N = 8k + 3$.  Then $N^2 + N \equiv 3^2 + 3 \equiv 12 \equiv 4 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: $N\equiv 3 \pmod 4 \to N\equiv 6 \pmod 8 $ which is not true. $N\equiv 7 \pmod 8 \to 14 \pmod {16}$. For $N=14$ $\frac{N^2 + N}{2} = 105 \equiv 9 \pmod {16}$ which is not 14

Comment: @user716881 Note $N \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ means there's a $k$ where $N - 3 = 4k \implies 2N - 6 \equiv 8k \implies 2N \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$, not $N \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$. Likewise, for your statement about $N \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$ implying $N \equiv 14 \pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

In arithmetic mod $4$, you cannot divide by $4$ or $2$. It is like dividing by $0$ in normal arithmetic; you can write the expression but there is no number that is equal to it.

If you divide and multiply by zero you can prove that all numbers are equal. This is of course inconsistent with our normal arithmetic, and also with modular arithmetics. The reason is that you cannot divide by zero.

If you allow division by zero you get the uninteresting arithmetic where there is only a single number.

Note that the second line is a legal equation, and its solutions, by trial and error, are $3$ and $4$.

Your example is interesting in the way it disguises $0$ as $4$, and also as $2$, since $2=\sqrt{4}=\sqrt{0}=0$.

I hadn't seen an example like this using modular arithmetic.

Comment: The question this working is from said $\frac{N^2+N}{2}$ is divisible by 4 so I wrote $\frac{N^2+N}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ .

Comment: For N=1 it isn't true. If you are solving $/frac{N^2+N}{2}=4k$ for some $k$, try $N^2+N=8k$ instead.

Comment: In fact we may be able to divide by integers not coprime to the modulus, but the key point is that the result may not be *unique* when it exists (though it can be made unique by decreasing the modulus). So your first sentence is a bit misleading as it stands.

Answer (score -1):

$(2N+1)^{2} \equiv 1  $

$2N+1 \equiv 1$

This step is wrong, for example: $(2*3+1)^2 \equiv 1$.

Comment: Note that $3$ lines further down, the OP later covers the other case, i.e., $2N + 1 \equiv 3$.