# MONT problem 2.8.2 , finding remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be any prime. Show that the remainder when $(p-1)!$ is divided by $p(p-1)$ is $p-1$

I have attached my solution below.
Can someone please confirm it, and if you find any mistake in it, please do tell.

Thanks in advance

From wilson's theorem, we know :

$$(p-1)! ≡ -1 ≡ p-1 (mod\ p)$$

$$(p-2)! ≡ 1 (mod\ p)$$

so, we get,

$$ (p-2)! = pk +1 $$
$$ (p-1)! = p(p-1)k + (p-1)$$

and clearly, the remainder is $p-1$,

Hence proved

Comment: Please identify which step(s) in the proof you have doubts about, and why. If there are no such doubts then there is no need to post the question.

Comment: Perfect.................

Comment: It is correct. You are essentially applying CRT to solve $x\equiv -1\pmod{p},\ x\equiv 0\pmod{p-1},\,$ which is **easy** since one modulus is $\equiv \pm1 $ mod the other, so in the CRT formula we only need to invert $\pm 1$, see [**Easy** Inverse CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2147772/242)

Comment: You should *justify* why cancelling $\,p-1\,$ from the first congruence yields an *equivalent* congruence (hint: this can fail if the fatcor being  cancelled is not coprime to the modulus), and you should explicitly signify such equivalences between sll congruences (use $\!\iff\!$ to relate them or use natural language) else [the proof may be insufficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4096963/242)