# How to find the inverse element to a number in the residue ring modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I don't understand how to find the inverse element to $7$ in the residue ring modulo $449$. According to Euclid's algorithm, I get $-64$, although the answer should be the number $385$. But at the same time $-64 + 449 = 385$. But how do I get $385$ initially?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Did you mean to write $385$ instead of $38$?

Comment: $-64$ is $385$ mod $449$ so there's no problem.  The algorithm will not always return the coefficient in the range you want it, but that's not a dealbreaker (and also not the hard part anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the inverse modulo $m$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Euclidean algorithm, which is a single step:

$449=7 \times 64+1$

$449 - 7 \times 64 = 1$

$ - 7 \times 64 = -449 + 1$

$ 7 \times (-64) \equiv  1 \mod{449}$

So the congruence class $-64$ is your answer.

Typically you would choose a term from $0... \; 448$ to represent the class

$-64 + 449 = 385$

To double check: $385 \times 7 = 2695$, and $2695=6 \times 449 + 1$ as desired.

Comment: Thank youThank you very much, I blunted something